# Unable to redirect users to Google for authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I have the following code to authenticate users using Google in `node.js`. I use the `passport-google-oauth` module. While I'm fairly sure the code is correct, the app simply won't redirect me to the Google login page. Please help me out.

Here is the code (using `express.js 4.9.0`):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: MY CLIENT ID,
    clientSecret: MY CLIENT SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:1337/auth/google/callback"
},
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        return done(null, profile);
    });
}
));
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'victoriassecret' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //res.render('index', { title: 'Collaborative' });
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'login.html'));
});

app.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
}),
function (req, res) {
    // The request will be redirected to Google for authentication, so this
    // function will not be called.
});

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/profile');
});

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.listen(1337);
module.exports = app;
```